# Clear stack policy in Cloudformation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

After creating a stack in CloudFormation, I set policy, which prohibits updates against the stack.  Later, I decided I still want to keep changing the environment, I'd like to clear the set policy.

I set StackPolicy with aws cli, so looked again the `aws cloudformation help` command.  Grepped `stack-policy` and all I found was `set-stack-policy` and `get-stack-policy`.

I also tried to set empty-ish policy with `aws cloudformation set-stack-policy --stack-name $STACK_NAME --stack-policy-body '{"Statement": []}'`, which resulted in:

```
An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the SetStackPolicy operation: Error validating stack policy: Invalid stack policy
```

#### Question

- Is there any way to clear a stack policy from a stack, after some policy has been set?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to [Amazon's own documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/protect-stack-resources.html#protect-stack-resources-modifying), you can't delete (clear) a stack policy from a stack.  They don't bother explain *why*, but they do suggest a workaround:

---

> You can't delete a stack policy. To remove all protection from all resources, you modify the policy to explicitly allow all actions on all resources. The following policy allows all updates on all resources:

.

```
{
  "Statement" : [
    {
      "Effect" : "Allow",
      "Action" : "Update:*",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Resource" : "*"
    }  
  ]
}
```

which is essentially equivalent to not having a stack policy attached at all.